# how do i get access to isolate scope in controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.6.

How do i get access to isolate scope from within a directive? Let's say I wanted to output some value from my isolate scope and add some additional text to the string before I print it out.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('appStore', []);

  angular.module('appStore', [])
    .directive('productTitle', function nw($scope){
      return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'product-title.html',
        scope : {
          namer : '='   // i'm passing a string in here.
        },
        link : function(scope, elem){
          scope.namer = scope.namer + ' additional text';  // when output, i get undefined + additional text.
        },
        controller : function($scope){
          $scope.namer = "test";  // this cause injection error
        }
      };
    });

}());
```

Comment: First problem is on line no. 4 where you are registering an already registered module so change angular.module('appStore', []).directive to angular.module('appStore').directive

Comment: Also, you cannot inject $scope in your directive function as your directive is isolating its scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems Identified:**

1. Registering your modules **multiple** times.
2. Using **'='** binding instead of **'@'** for getting string in directive.
3. Injecting **$scope** in directive which is **not allowed** in angular.

Below code works fine as expected:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appStore')
    .directive('productTitle', productTitle);

  function productTitle() {
    // Usage:
    //     <product-title></product-title>
    var productTitle = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        namer: '@' // Use @ binding to take pass strings to directive
      },
      templateUrl: 'product-title.html',
      // Uncomment controller to check your controller function works fine
      //controller: controller
    };
    return productTitle;

    function link(scope, elem) {
      scope.namer = scope.namer + ' additional text';
      console.log(scope.namer); //prints 'something additional text'
    }

    function controller($scope) {
      $scope.namer = "test"; //Changes namer to test and link prints 'test additional text'
    }
  }

})(angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="appStore">
    <product-title namer='something'></product-title>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="appStore.module.js"></script>
  <script src="productTitle.directive.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```